# json file to jinja2 template python

Tags: python, json, jinja2

i have a json file `vlans.json` that contains the following

```
{"1": {"description": "default", "name": "default"}, "2": {"description": "ilo", "name": "ILO"}}
```

my code looks like

```
from jinja2 import Template
import json

vlans_file = "vlans.json"

with open(vlans_file) as json_file:
    vlans = json.load(json_file)

vlan_template = Template('''
{% for vlan in vlans %}
#
vlan {{ vlan }}
 description {{ value }}
#
{% endfor %}

''')

print(vlan_template.render(vlans = vlans))
```

and it prints

```
#
vlan 1
 description 
#

#
vlan 2
 description 
#
```

does anyone know how to get the below output?

```
#
vlan 1
 description default
 name default
#
vlan 2
 description ilo
 name ilo
#
```

Comment: Instead of `{{ value }}` can you use `{{ vlan.description }}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have managed to solve it

```
from jinja2 import Template

vlans = {"1": {"description": "default", "name": "default"}}

vlan_template = Template('''
{% for key,value in vlans.items() %}
#
vlan {{ key }}
 description {{ value["description"] }}
 name {{ value["name"] }}
#
{% endfor %}

''')

print(vlan_template.render(vlans = vlans))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first take the json and make it a python dictionary ( maybe try requests )
then :
vlans_file = {"1": {"description": "default", "name": "default"}, "2":   {"description": "ilo", "name": "ILO"}}

```
for a,b in vlans_file.items():
    print("vlan {}".format(a))
    for x in b.items():
        print(x)
```

output :
vlan 1
('description', 'default')
('name', 'default')
vlan 2
('description', 'ilo')
('name', 'ILO')

Comment: Did you try the requests module ? JSON_filename.JSON()

Comment: no, i haven't, i'm hoping to solve all of this only with jinja template...